# Put ggplot output into 2 rows

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to make a histogram by groups. How can I put them in 2 rows?

This is my code:

```
# histograms:
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(ind_bask, aes(x = inpatient)) +
  geom_density(color = "grey30", fill = "white") +
  facet_grid(~id)
```

And this is the output I get: 
[image]

I would like it to go in 2 rows.

Thanks

Comment: You want to use `facet_wrap()` and not `facet_grid()` in to specify the number of rows and columns.

Comment: Thanks that's perfect!